# Problema al descargar archivo en python

Tags: python, python-requests, descarga, wget

Estoy intentando **descargar unos microdatos del Instituto Canario de Estadística**, concretamente los microdatos de la Encuesta sobre el Gasto Turístico del primer trimestre de 2020.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/istac/galerias/documentos/C00028A/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q1.html'
EGT = requests.get(url)
EGT
```

Y python me devuelve :  `<Response [200]>`

También he intentado:

```
import wget
 
url = 'http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/istac/galerias/documentos/C00028A/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q1.html'
wget.download(url, 'C:\Trabajo\ISTAC_project\ISTAC_python/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q1.html')
```

Que genera un archivo `.html` con la dirección donde están los microdatos en formato zip que necesito pero no me descarga el archivo.

**¿Cómo puedo entonces descargar el archivo?**

Comment: Con `wget` deberías hacer algo así: `wget.download(url, 'C:\Trabajo\archivo.zip')`

Comment: Con ```wget``` y tu sugerencia lo he conseguido. Pero preferiría hacerlo con ```requests``` ¿Sabes dónde puedo estar equivocándome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import requests
import os

url = 'http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/istac/galerias/documentos/C00028A/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q1.html'

# permitimos la redireccion con allow_redirects=True
EGT = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)

"""
 obtenemos la nueva url
 que nos devuelve la redireccion
 split("/") creamos un arreglo de la url separado por el caracter /
 y con [-1] obtenemos el ultimo elemento del arreglo 

"""
name = EGT.url.split("/")[-1]
# obtenemos el path
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),name)

# abrimos un archivo en modo wb = write/binary y + es crear si no existe
with open(path,"wb+") as f:
    # escribimos el contenido devuelto dentro del archivo
    f.write(EGT.content)


print("descarga completa en {}".format(path))
```

Comment: Cuando ejecuto el código de tu solución, no se me descarga el archivo pero tampoco aparece un error, no ocurre nada.

Comment: revisa bien... el archivo debe estar en la ruta donde se encuentra tu script, igual edite para que no te equivoques!

Comment: Tenías razón, se estaba descargando pero en la capreta de usuario, que no es donde está el script ¿Cómo podría hacer para que se descargara en la carpeta donde está el script?

Comment: Ya está, cambiando el directorio con ```os.chdr()```. Supongo que será típico despiste de novato.

Comment: puedes cambiar `os.getcwd()` por la ruta donde deseas que se guarde!

Answer (score 1):

Esta alternativa lee y guarda el archivo en disco. No lo descomprime. El resultado final es que tienes un `datos.zip` en tu directorio.

La solución define una función `download_url` que recibe la URL y un nombre de archivo de salida. Opcionalmente puedes indicar el tamaño del buffer de lectura.

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/istac/galerias/documentos/C00028A/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q1.html'

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

download_url(url, "datos.zip", 1024)
```

Comment: Al ejecutarlo, no se me descarga el archivo pero tampoco me devuelve un error, no ocurre nada.

Comment: Deja el archivo en el directorio. ¿Cual directorio? Depende de donde lo ejecutes. Prueba con un path absoluto para verificar que funcione.